# Unable to load data from Cassandra table in PySpark app

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Unable to load data from cassandra; I understand issue is with guava jar; tried different versions of guava; unable to identify the expected version of jar. (replaced with datastax shared jar as well)

Version - Scala  2.11.12, Spark  2.3.2.3.1.4.41-3
jars using spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.3.2.jar,cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar, commons-configuration-1.7.jar, java-driver-shaded-guava-25.1-jre.jar or one off guava jars version 19/24/31  at time of spark submit.

pyspark script & spark submit after the below:

```
Error:
  File "cass.py", line 6, in <module>
    data_df = ss.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(keyspace="xxxxx",table="xxxxx").load()
  File "/disk-3/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/vdfidt1/appcache/application_1660663467107_0171/container_e68_1660663467107_0171_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
  File "/disk-3/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/vdfidt1/appcache/application_1660663467107_0171/container_e68_1660663467107_0171_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/disk-3/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/vdfidt1/appcache/application_1660663467107_0171/container_e68_1660663467107_0171_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/disk-3/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/vdfidt1/appcache/application_1660663467107_0171/container_e68_1660663467107_0171_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o103.load.

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o103.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Objects.firstNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.datastax.driver.core.policies.Policies$Builder.build(Policies.java:285)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.getConfiguration(Cluster.java:1246)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:116)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:181)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1264)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:131)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:159)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:32)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.syncAcquire(RefCountedCache.scala:69)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:57)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:79)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.dht.TokenFactory$.forSystemLocalPartitioner(TokenFactory.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

pyscript - cass.py

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,SQLContext

ss = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark cassandra").getOrCreate()
data_df = ss.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(keyspace="reg_idt1_vdf",table="veh")
    .load()
data_df.show()
ss.stop()
```

spark submit - cass.sh

```
function setJars() {
    i=0
    for file in /home/tst1/*.jar
    do
       JARS=${JARS},${file}
    done
}

setJars
    
spark-submit \
    --name 'pyspark cassandra connector' \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --driver-memory 2g \
    --executor-memory 2g \
    --num-executors 20 \
    --jars ${JARS} \
    --conf "spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1" \
    --conf "spark.cassandra.connection.host=xx.xx.xx.xx" \
    --conf "spark.cassandra.auth.username=xxxxx" \
    --conf "spark.cassandra.auth.password=xxxxxx" \
    --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true" \
    --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=100" \
    --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=10"  \
    --conf "spark.executor.cores=2" \
    --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=500s" \
    --conf "spark.authenticate=true" \
    $/home/tst1/cass.py
    exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the problem is that there is a conflict in the components you've packaged with your app. For reference, the list of dependencies + corresponding versions for Spark Cassandra connector v2.3.2 are [documented in `Versions.scala`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v2.3.2/project/Versions.scala).

Also, there is no need to include the Cassandra Java driver since the connector already embeds the driver automatically.

Our general recommendation is to launch `spark-submit` with the `--packages` option. For example:

```
$ spark-submit --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.3.2-s_2.11
```

This will automatically download all the necessary dependencies to use the connector. This also ensures that only the compatible versions are included.

If you really want to build a fat JAR, you can download [the "assembly" JAR from Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly) if one exists for your Spark version. The connector assembly JAR contains all the dependencies required to use the connector. Cheers!

Comment: thanks a lot @Eric Ramirez; appreciate the reference.
tried it; dealing with firewall issues :). supplied a fat jar still no success.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.3.2/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.3.2.pom

Answer (score 0):

@Eric Ramirez
as I am unable to use "--packages" due to firewall issues,
finally able to pull data from cassandra by providing the entire suite of dependencies mentioned in the maven pom.
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.3.2/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.3.2.pom

Thanks a lot!!